# android studio Espresso have no complete recording button

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3, android-espresso-recorder

I'm using android studio 2.3.2 I want to create a record espresso test, but when I finish creation, it only "Add Assertion" button, no "complete recording" button, I can't start UI record test. if you see the picture you will understand my confusion.

[image: picture]

Comment: have you tried the OK button at the bottom of the recorder?

Comment: I tried, press OK button then studio will generate code for me, but this code didn't work，I even have not start record my test process. I was wonder why my studio Not the same as others